# Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: String could not be parsed as XML

Tags: php, xml

В общем как я понял, ошибка заключается в том, что файлы передаются строкой; есть еще один нюанс: данная ошибка вылезает только при включенном vpn; т.е. если vpn выключен, то все работает нормально и ошибка не вылезает

Вот xml:

```
<ValCurs Date="31.03.2023" name="Foreign Currency Market">
  <Valute ID="R01010">
    <NumCode>036</NumCode>
    <CharCode>AUD</CharCode>
    <Nominal>1</Nominal>
    <Name>Австралийский доллар</Name>
    <Value>51,5476</Value>
  </Valute>
    <Valute ID="R01020A">
    <NumCode>944</NumCode>
    <CharCode>AZN</CharCode>
    <Nominal>1</Nominal>
    <Name>Азербайджанский манат</Name>
    <Value>45,3449</Value>
  </Valute>
  <Valute ID="R01035">
    <NumCode>826</NumCode>
    <CharCode>GBP</CharCode>
    <Nominal>1</Nominal>
    <Name>Фунт стерлингов Соединенного королевства</Name>
    <Value>94,9009</Value>
  </Valute>
</ValCurs>
```

вот php:

```
$ch = curl_init();  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "$link"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
 
$result = curl_exec($ch);
 
$xml = $result;
$xml_obj = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
```

Comment: Выведи на экран `$result` и посмотри что там.

Comment: Я разобрался. Причина была как раз в xml файле, который не грузил валюты из-за ограничений в доступе